# golang liteide - could not parse action

Tags: build, ide, go, liteide

I just installed and set up Lite Ide. When I try to run my simple "Hello World" program, I get these error messages,

> Could not parse action 'Build'
>
> Could not parse action 'Run'

Any ideas why I'm getting these errors?

Edit: When I go to View -> Manage GOPATH, the System GOPATH field shows up to be empty, even though I have the following in my bashrc:

```
 export GOPATH=~/Desktop/go
 export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Comment: Do you have the Go libraries installed on your computer, and is LiteIDE pointed correctly to them?

Comment: I installed Go, and I can run my programs from the terminal. But get this message when I try to run them from LiteIDE. What libraries should I look for and how do I check whether LiteIDE is pointing correctly to them?

Comment: Go to `View > Manage GOPATH`

Comment: System GOPATH is empty, even though I have it in my bashrc:     export GOPATH=~/Desktop/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin

Comment: Set it manually in LiteIDE